# Implementation of correlation matrix in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, correlation

I want to implement the following formula in MATLAB, where u_i^(k) means the i,k element. However, I get different results from the ones I compute by hand... I believe that something is wrong with my MATLAB code. For instance,
I should get:

```
L_ii =

    0.1022         0         0
         0    0.1657         0
         0         0    2.7321

U_ij =

    0.7514    0.3104    0.5823
   -0.6513    0.4901    0.5793
   -0.1055   -0.8145    0.5704

1,1=1-(0.1022*(+0.7514)^2+0.1657*(+0.3104)^2+2.7321*(+0.5823)^2)=-0.000049
2,2=1-(0.1022*(-0.6513)^2+0.1657*(+0.4901)^2+2.7321*(+0.5793)^2)=-0.000015
3,3=1-(0.1022*(-0.1055)^2+0.1657*(-0.8145)^2+2.7321*(+0.5704)^2)=+0.000030
```

Any ideas??? Please, help me fix Epsilon first (it might not need to move on Rho. Let's fix Epsilon first...)

[image]

[image]

EDIT: Here is a sample code:

```
E_squared_ii = ONES_j - diag(L_ii)' * (U_ij'.^ 2)
```

And here is the *wrong* result I get at the moment:

```
E_squared_ii =

   1.0e-15 *

   0.444089209850063   0.333066907387547  -0.222044604925031
```

Comment: You have to put your existing code so that it can be analyzed.

Comment: So the above is what you *should* get; what do you *actually* get?

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: Just updated the question.

Comment: The simplest way to do these type of computation is to use for loops, although it is slower but it is always easy to implement. Is this something you want me to show you how to do? Or for loop is not acceptable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I use your values and code, I get the expected result:

```
>> L_ii

L_ii =

    0.1022         0         0
         0    0.1657         0
         0         0    2.7321

>> U_ij

U_ij =

    0.7514    0.3104    0.5823
   -0.6513    0.4901    0.5793
   -0.1055   -0.8145    0.5704

>> ONES_j

ONES_j =

     1     1     1

>> E_squared_ii = ONES_j - diag(L_ii)' * (U_ij'.^ 2)

E_squared_ii =

   1.0e-04 *

   -0.4935   -0.1451    0.2985
```

Presumably this means that something isn't the value you think it is...

Comment: You are right, just restarted MATLAB and now it works... LOL!